# VSIX - Getting Selected Project Assembly Info

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix

What is the easiest way to retrieve Assembly Info?

I have access to selected Project and can get access to AssemblyInfo.cs class through traversing ProjectItems.

I need information like Project Version, Author, Company, Copyright, Cultur, GUid etc.

This is the code to get selected Project.

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 _applicationObject = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE));
        UIHierarchy solutionExplorerHirarechy = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
        Array solutionExplorerSelectedItems = (Array)solutionExplorerHirarechy.SelectedItems;

        if (null != solutionExplorerSelectedItems)
        {
            Project selectedProject = ((UIHierarchyItem)solutionExplorerSelectedItems.GetValue(0)).Object as Project;
            return selectedProject;
        }
```

Comment: Microsoft uses Roslyn to get that information when it populates the Assembly Attributes dialog in Visual Studio.  Here is the Microsoft GitHub code that gets that information.  https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/280